# Default "top 20 answerers" link in tag wiki does not resolve correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

For example, the wiki page for J: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/j/info

Has the following link for "top 20 answerers": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=stats&Tag.Name=j

But leads to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Shouldn't it be: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/j/stats ?

Comment: @waffles, am I going too fast about this? Because I still see no change.

Comment: This is still not fixed for me either. Possible that it's a caching issue. I would wait 5 minutes and if it's still happening then try flagging the post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in dev and on meta ... will be deployed to SO later today ...